# Does google play modify or optimise the published APK?

Tags: android, google-play

I know that google play generated an optimized APK for a given App Bundle (aab).

But if one publishes the old format (APK), does google play modify the apk to make it smaller? Does the user download the whole apk on every update?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Note from August next year, you will only have to download aab.

Comment: "But if one publishes the old format (APK), does google play modify the apk to make it smaller? Does the user download the whole apk on every update?"

Yes to which question? Yes to both is contradicting.

Also, is there any documentation that shows that?

Comment: Loads unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play does not make APKs smaller as it isn't designed for that. AAB are the new upload format and Google Play generates APKs from AAB depending on the device (screen density, abi, language etc) as well as bringing many new features such as dynamic modules.

> Google Play uses your app bundle to generate and serve optimized APKs for each device configuration, so only the code and resources that are needed for a specific device are downloaded to run your app. You no longer have to build, sign, and manage multiple APKs to optimize support for different devices, and users get smaller, more-optimized downloads.

More information: https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle